# Delete facebook comment from my site or facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook javascript SDK to post comment on facebook and using this code:

```
FB.init({
            //appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie: true,
            appId: '2697XXXXXXXXXX098', cookie: true,
            status: true, xfbml: true
        });

                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'MyComment',
                    link: 'http://www.facebook.com./',
                    picture: 'http://xyz.com/App_Shared/Images/logo.jpg',
                    caption: 'Comment caption',
                    description: 'comment description',
                    message: 'Join facebook.'
                }, function (response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        alert('Post was published.' + response.post_id);
                    } else {
                        alert('Post was not published.');
                    }
                });
```

and now i want to delete this post by using the same type of js code.
I saved post_id in my database.

Can you provide me the code or any URL to do this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must give to access to you application and allow by user according to this URL

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

These permission you can use like this method

```
 FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    jQuery('#hdfUID1').val(response.id);
                    jQuery('#btnFBLoginTemp').click();
                    //                        FB.logout(function (response) {
                    //                        });
                });
            } else {
                jQuery('#hdfUID1').val('');
            }
        }, { scope: 'email,user_photos,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' });
```

if user allow these permissions then you can delete comment from user's wall which was posted by your application by using "Anatoly Lubarsky" answer method....

```
FB.api(postId, 'delete', function(response) {
    // callback here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

should be very simple like:

```
FB.api(postId, 'delete', function(response) {
    // callback here
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: I user this but it gives me error : {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}}

Comment: @Gaurav this requires publish_stream extended permission